# Bundle ID domain extension asked for during ios app submission

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

If my company's domain name extension is .gov would my bundle id be gov.mycompanyname.myappname (rather than com.mycompanyname.myappname commonly used as an example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, there is no restriction, just that it should be unique.  Reverse dns is just a simple way to insure uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing for this issue is that it matches what your distribution certificate was created for. If you are releasing with the .* profile, you can name it whatever you like. If you created one gov.yourcompany.appname, then you need to make sure you have it set that way in your Info.plist file.